# SSH XMSS keypair generation and best practices

Tags: ssh, key-generation, openssh, xmss

In a recent `ssh -vv` output, I saw OpenSSH mentioning a private key file `id_xmss`.

XMSS is defined in [RFC 8391, "XMSS: eXtended Merkle Signature Scheme", May 2018](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8391/).

OpenSSH has experimental support for XMSS since [version 7.7 (2018-04-02)](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7).

- How do I generate an XMSS keypair? With OpenSSH?
- What are best practices for key generation parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary XMSS support was added in [OpenSSH 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7) but it's still [considered experimental](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.1) and as of OpenSSH 9.2 still not enabled by default. In OpenBSD one can enable XMSS support by compiling [usr.bin/ssh](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/) like this:

```
$ export WITH_XMSS=yes
$ cd /usr/src/
$ make -j$(/sbin/sysctl -n hw.ncpu) -C usr.bin/ssh/
$ usr.bin/ssh/ssh-keygen/obj/ssh-keygen -t xmss
[...]
```

However, because XMSS support is not officially supported by OpenSSH just yet, I would not recommend using it *except for testing*. Once support will be official, I'm sure the [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen.1) will be updated accordingly on how to generate XMSS keys safely (bits, rounds, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In order to this, you must first compile with `WITH_XMSS`

```
./configure
make libopenssh ssh-keygen CFLAGS=-DWITH_XMSS=1
```

Then you can either call it by the [`short_name` or the `long_name`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/27267642699342412964aa785b98afd69d952c88/ssh-xmss.c#L364) Like this,

```
./ssh-keygen -t xmss
./ssh-keygen -t ssh-xmss@openssh.com
```

---

Note compilation is required because xmss is experimental (disabled by default), and potentially even insecure as [bugs have been discovered that would allow local code execution (since patched).](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-16905)